# java - bank system - passing arraylist from main to JFrame Table

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jtable

so I've created a arraylist with a a transaction.
Im trying to pass this information to mt Frame class with a table in it.
It is not happening. Please help

```
public class AccountsClass {
private int AccountNumber;
private String AccName;
private double Balance;
private String Date; 
public ArrayList Transactions;


public void NewAccount (){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("New Account Number? ");
  this.AccountNumber = in.nextInt();
  in.nextLine();

  System.out.print("Account Name? ");
  this.AccName = in.nextLine();

  System.out.print("Initial Balance ? ");
  this.Balance = in.nextInt();
  in.nextLine();

  System.out.print("Open Date? ");
  this.Date = in.nextLine();

  Transactions = new ArrayList();
  Transactions.add(AccountNumber);
  Transactions.add(AccName);
  Transactions.add(Balance);
  Transactions.add(Date);
```

this is my Jframe table class:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */



public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    addtoJ();
    System.out.print("jjjjjj ");
}
public ArrayList Record;


public void addtoJ ()

{DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

// Record1 = new Record;
// new Record = AccountsClass.Transactions;
    //Record = new ArrayList();

    Record = AccountsClass.Transactions;

    Object rowData[] = new Object[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < Record.size(); i++)
    {
        rowData[0] = Record.get(i);
        rowData[1] = Record.get(i);
        rowData[2] = Record.get(i);
        rowData[3] = Record.get(i);
        model.addRow(rowData);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error message regarding non static to static. I'm trying to create a list of transactions for a Bank Statement

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access non-static variables and methods via the Class itself.
You need to create an object of that class then use it to get the variable.

But for your case you want your `AccountsClass.Transactions` to be static.

```
public static ArrayList Transactions;

public static void NewAccount (){...}
```

Also PLEASE follow the standards in naming classes and methods and variables. It will help you in the future.
Transactions should be transactions.
NewAccount method should be just a constructer of the class.
AccountsClass should be Accounts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8811160/saud-aljaffer @saudaljaffer

Comment: @Saud Sorry I can't give out my contact info. I suggest if you followed a course where you have to create a mini project in Java. This way you will learn by experience.

Comment: *"Is there a way I can connect with you to ask for proper help?"* It is not OK to try and solicit off-site help via Stack Overflow. This is intended as a  public repository of questions and answers, not a place to source a tutor.